# Create in-memory database with hibernate and load data into

Tags: java, hibernate, h2

For testing issues, I would like to create an in-memory database. One of the tables should have content by default. How do I do this?
I tried with the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `test`;</property>
    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">test</property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">initial_data.sql</property>
</session-factory>
```

The file initial_data.sql is simple:

```
INSERT INTO test.email_template(template_id, description, subject, text, sender, reply_to)
VALUES('1','Confirm','Your registration','Some content here','no_reply@mail.com',NULL);
```

But when I start the tests, I get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : HHH000388: Unsuccessful:    VALUES('1','Confirm','Your registration','Some content here','no_reply@mail.com',NULL)
2016-12-29 13:53:30.826 ERROR 6560 --- [ main]    org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport  : Method is not allowed for a query. Use execute or executeQuery instead of executeUpdate; SQL statement:
```

What is wrong?

Comment: When you ask a question about an exception, always post the complete stack trace of the exception, and the relevant code.

Comment: The given exception is everything I get.

Answer (score 0):

I think Hibernate has an issue with multi-line SQL.
Try to put all parts of any single query on a single line:

```
INSERT INTO test.email_template(template_id, description, subject, text, sender, reply_to) VALUES('1','Confirm','Your regitration','Some content here','no_reply@mail.com',NULL);
```

or use the following config:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor">org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.M‌​ultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor</property>
```